# Use 2 (or more) colors for a button text

Tags: android, colors, android-view, android-button

I know I can change the color of the text on a button by the following ways :

```
button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.red)); //TAKE DEFAULT COLOR
```

or

```
button.setTextColor(0xff0000); //SET CUSTOM COLOR
```

or

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

However I want to use two colors for the text : for example, suppose my button has the following text : "Click Here" , I want the "Click" part to appear in red, and the "Here" part in blue.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use **ForegroundColorSpan**

Try like this,

```
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Click Here");
        // make "Clicks" (characters 0 to 5) Red
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);
        // make "Here" (characters 6 to 10) Blue
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 6, 10, 0);
        // shove our styled text into the Button
        b.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**OutPut**:

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for going the extra step and printing out a screen shot. highly appreciated.

Comment: the spannable thing is java or android specific ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible

do like this

```
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Click</font>"
            + "<font color='blue'> Here</font>"));
```