# Displaying button's text with two different colors

Tags: java, android, button, text, colors

So I'm able to display textView's text with different color using

```
String redString= "<font color='#ee0000'>yay</font>";
String blackString = "<font color='#000000'>eureka</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString + blackString));
```

but when trying to do exactly the same with

```
button.setText(...)
```

it doesn't work! Do you know if it's possible to have different colors in button's text? If not, are there any alternative solutions?

EDIT: I tried both solutions suggested but none of them worked. I created a new project just to be sure:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //first solution
    String redString= "<font color='#ee0000'>yay </font>";
    String blackString = "<font color='#000000'>eureka</font>";
    TextView test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button test2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    test1.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString + blackString));
    test2.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString + blackString));

    //second solution
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello World");
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0);
    text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, text.length(), 0);
    b.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsM7J.png) (sorry but I can't display the image due to low reputation)

I'm using AS 2.3.3 on Windows 10. The emulator uses Android 7 with API 25. Thanks for helping!

Comment: you can use simple linear layout(horizontal) with text view as button and setOnClickListener on this linear layout .

Comment: check SpannableString

Comment: possible solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500350/use-2-or-more-colors-for-a-button-text). Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use 2 (or more) colors for a button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500350/use-2-or-more-colors-for-a-button-text)

Comment: Please, describe `... it doesn't work!`.

Comment: @ModularSynth the whole text is default color

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use This code

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello World");

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0);

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 5, text.length(), 0);

b.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: tried but didn't work, button's text color is still default! result in the edit part

Answer (score 1):

It works for me...

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ettx);

        Button test2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ettxb);

        String redString= "<font color='#ee0000'>yay</font>";
        String blackString = "<font color='#000000'>eureka</font>";
        test.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString + blackString));

        test2.setText(Html.fromHtml(redString + blackString));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have `android:textAllCaps = true` for your button it might not work. Try setting it to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Color Change");

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 5, 0);

text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 5, text.length(), 0);

b.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```